# Connect to an ejabberd server from another machine

Tags: installation, ejabberd

I have ejabberd installed on my windows 7 machine .I created users using the web admin and clients are connecting fine.(I am using psi). I want for the users on other machines to be able to connect and even users with android clients.

I have modified the hosts file in

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

like this:

```
127.0.0.1       domain.tz
192.168.0.161   domain.tz
```

192.168.0.161 is the ip address of the machine the server is installed on.I can ping it from other machines but when i try to connect a user with let say usr: user1@domain.tz pwd: passwrd it says the server can't  be reached. What do I need to do to let clients connect successfuly to my ejabberd server?I apologize if this is basic but this is my first trial on xmpp server administration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with my own understanding with DNS .The domain name you set up when you set up your xmpp server should be an already existing ACCESSIBLE address on the network. I found the name of my pc simply by running the famous

```
ipconfig/all
```

on windows and used the host name value as my domain while setting up ejabberd.It usually even finds it by default.

NOTE: To reconfigure ejabberd ,I uninstalled it and deleted everything in the

```
C:\Users\myUserName\AppData\Roaming\ejabberd.
```

If i didn't do so ,the last settings of the server are not deleted and you can't create your new admin account.These are my findings on ejabberd so far and I hope it helps somebody some day.